# fotorama skipping slides contents

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2, fotorama

I am using fotorama, and it's awesome.
Problem is, for some reason Fotorama 4.5.0 is skipping certain slides' contents.

Link: http://limudim.psychometry.co.il/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A1

Click on one of the links in slide #1 - the button is supposed to become grey
Now do the same on one of the buttons in slide #2 - same behavior
Now go to slide #3 - none of the buttons is responding
Same in slide #4 and #5

Slide #6 for some reason is working properly

Same weird thing happens here:
http://limudim.psychometry.co.il/afeka/home.php

Slide to the bottom of the page where there's a picture carousel, and click on one of the pictures. It's suppose to open a fancybox window which you can scroll with your mouse roller.

It's suppose to display 60 pictures, but for some reason it displays only 8 pictures in a row.

Weird, huh?

I've been looking for solutions in Google, here, and nothing came up.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use the fullscren option from fotorama instead fancybox ?

here there is information how to use it http://fotorama.io/customize/fullscreen/